# I require signed commits, but I need to disable signing for refs/notes/commits

Tags: git, gerrit

I'm using gerrit 2.8 and require signed commits. However, I'd like for notes to not require signing. What permissions might I use?

```
git notes add -F ~/note.txt <hash>
git push origin refs/notes/commits:refs/notes/commits
...
 ! [remote rejected] refs/notes/commits -> refs/notes/commits (not Signed-off-by author/committer/uploader in commit message footer)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://A/project'
```

I have edited the project.config to add these lines:

```
[access "refs/notes/commits"]
        push = group Administrators
        create = group Administrators
+       requireSignedOffBy = false
+       requireChangeId = false
```

to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Shawn Pearce, [this is not supported as of 2.8](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/repo-discuss/EZS1bCskG2s).

> You can't. The option is unfortunately applied to the entire project. I see how this is a reasonable feature request, but its simply not understood or supported by the server.